# Error: [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/rest/RequestHandler' is not defined by /node_modules/eris/package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start, eris

So i'm really new to this type of stuff. When running my 'npm start' command, it keeps dropping the following error below:

```
[ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/rest/RequestHandler' is not defined by "exports" in /root/InviteManagerV2/node_modules/eris/package.json
```

I've looked up the error many times and 'deleting all the files and reinstalling' didn't work, neither did a update. Do you guys have any idea on how i can fix this? Any help would be great!

Here is my startup script:

```html
    "scripts": {
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node scripts/dev-run.js",
        "debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node scripts/dev-run.js debug",
        "build": "tsc",
        "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json --format stylish",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"docs/**/*.md\" \"README.md\" \"CHANGELOG.md\"",
        "release": "npm run build && npm run docs && npm run format && standard-version",
        "i18n": "node scripts/check-i18n.js",
        "nxv": "node ./scripts/npm-exact-versions.js",
        "docs": "node scripts/generate-docs.js"
    },
```

Comment: try  this `npm update`

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, i (think) i've added my startup script (i dont know much about this lol) npm update sadly does not fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

1. install a npm package `env-cmd` [package documentation][1]

   `npm install env-cmd`
2. make a folder in **root** directory of project, name it as **config** and create a file in it called as **dev.env**
3. Define your environment variables in this dev.env for eg  `PORT=3000`
4. then add this line to your package.json file

   `"start ": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env node scripts/dev-run.js"`

Comment: Tried both of those, sadly i still have the same error

Comment: Updated my answer, this works :) its a clean approach and helps you to define various environment variable depending on your use case for eg  for development seperate env file and for production different env variables